# Inserting to SQL Server NTEXT Field

Tags: sql-server, laravel, laravel-query-builder, ntext

I want to insert a row into a SQL Server table via Laravel Query Builder.

I'm converting unicode characters with the method below:

```
mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UCS-2LE', mb_detect_encoding($value, mb_detect_order(), true))
```

Everything works fine except for `ntext` fields. I cannot insert a row if there exists an `ntext` field. I can insert as `NULL`. But I cannot insert anyting in the `ntext` field.

But inserting for other types is working fine. And I'm getting a `SQL Server 206 error` when the data for the `ntext` field is not null.

What is the problem ?

Comment: Well, Unless you are working with a very old version of sql server (that is, before 2008), you souldn't use `text` or `ntext` at all. Instead, you should use `varchar(max)` or `nvarchar(max)`. If possible, I would suggest changing the data type of the `ntext` columns.

Comment: [Official reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms187993.aspx) of what Zohar said: `IMPORTANT!  ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.`

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the actual `INSERT` statement?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I'm not using these field types. This is not my system. I am building an integration system.